# Does the Pig split combination feature work with TextLoader?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

The Pig [cookbook](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.8.1/cookbook.html) states that split combination feature works with PigStorage but it does not state whether it works with TextLoader also. Does it? I am trying to have a more in depth understand of what is going on when I run Pig jobs.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it also works with TextLoader.